# distributing collect_list function across worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, collect

I am performing an aggregated array collection using the following code in pyspark:

```
df1=df.groupBy('key').agg(collect_list('value'))
```

I know functions like collect forces data into a single node. Is it possible to achieve the same result while at the same time leveraging the power of distributed cloud computing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of misunderstanding here

`collect` forces the data to be collected over driver and is not distributed

whereas

`collect_list` and `collect_set` are distributed operations by default.

Comment: But when I execute it, I see the load increasing only in one node in Gangila